# How to calculate the summary of the variable and saved as dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to calculate the summary of the variable and saved as dataframe for each variable in python

I have a pandas dataframe

```
Age_Bin Cat_Bin Outcome
  Age1    Cat2     0
  Age1    Cat1     1
  Age2    Cat2     1
  Age1    Cat1     1
  Age2    Cat1     0
  Age3    Cat1     0
  Age3    Cat2     0
  Age1    Cat1     1
  Age3    Cat2     1
```

calculated the summary of Outcome distribution of each variable as shown below using the below given code.

Example on Age_Bin variable

```
Age_Bin Outcome_0_cnt Outcome_1_cnt Total_cnt Outcome_0_cnt% Outcome_1_cnt%
  Age1         1         3           4           1/4            3/5
  Age2         1         1           2           1/4            1/5
  Age3         2         1           3           2/4            1/5
```

This has been achieved using the below code

```
    df1 = ( df.groupby(['Age_Bin','Outcome'])['Cat_Bin'] .size() .unstack(fill_value=0) .add_prefix('Outcome_') ) df = df1.assign(Total_cnt=lambda x: x.sum(1)).join(df1.div(df1.sum()).add_suffix('%')) 

    print (df) 

    Outcome Outcome_0 Outcome_1 Total_cnt Outcome_0% Outcome_1%
   Age_Bin 
    Age1         1       3          4         0.25     0.6 
    Age2         1       1          2         0.25     0.2 
    Age3         2       1          3         0.50     0.2
```

In addition to the above output, I need to include one more column Z next to Outcome_1%.

```
Z_Age= log(Outcome_1%/Outcome_0%).
```

Then the Z value of each variable mapped to original df based on each category as given

```
     Age_Bin Cat_Bin Outcome Z_Age Z_Cat
      Age1    Cat2     0
      Age1    Cat1     1
      Age2    Cat2     1
      Age1    Cat1     1
      Age2    Cat1     0
      Age3    Cat1     0
      Age3    Cat2     0
      Age1    Cat1     1
      Age3    Cat2     1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = (
       df.groupby(['Age_Bin','Outcome'])['Cat_Bin']
         .size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .add_prefix('Outcome_')
      )

df2 = df1.assign(Total_cnt=lambda x: x.sum(1)).join(df1.div(df1.sum()).add_suffix('%'))
print (df2)
Outcome  Outcome_0  Outcome_1  Total_cnt  Outcome_0%  Outcome_1%
Age_Bin                                                         
Age1             1          3          4        0.25         0.6
Age2             1          1          2        0.25         0.2
Age3             2          1          3        0.50         0.2
```

Then add:

```
df2 = df2.assign(Z_age=np.log(df2['Outcome_0%'] / df2['Outcome_1%']))
print (df2)
Outcome  Outcome_0  Outcome_1  Total_cnt  Outcome_0%  Outcome_1%     Z_age
Age_Bin                                                                   
Age1             1          3          4        0.25         0.6 -0.875469
Age2             1          1          2        0.25         0.2  0.223144
Age3             2          1          3        0.50         0.2  0.916291

#map new column by Age, not possible category because no information about it in df2
df['Z_Age'] = df['Age_Bin'].map(df2['Z_age'])
print (df)
  Age_Bin Cat_Bin  Outcome     Z_Age
0    Age1    Cat2        0 -0.875469
1    Age1    Cat1        1 -0.875469
2    Age2    Cat2        1  0.223144
3    Age1    Cat1        1 -0.875469
4    Age2    Cat1        0  0.223144
5    Age3    Cat1        0  0.916291
6    Age3    Cat2        0  0.916291
7    Age1    Cat1        1 -0.875469
8    Age3    Cat2        1  0.916291
```

Comment: Thanks it works as expected, but it creates multiple dataframe as I have many variables. Is there any function to append the results in one dataframe for all variables

Comment: Do you think `df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, ...])` - [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)?

Comment: The concat function would be useful to combine multiple df to one dataframe

Comment: The concat function would be useful to combine multiple df to one dataframe but it is not getting applied as these output are from group by. The structure is not usual row and column. Please see first column.

Comment: Can you explain more? It seems I dont understand what you need. How are created multiple dataframes?

Comment: Thanks, works well. I am creating a new variable, say z= Outcome_1%/Outcome_0%. But I need to put the Z value in the original dataframe as a new variable Z based on bin category like AGE_BIN etc

Comment: Can you edit question - input data annd expected output?